# Reading a stream from gstreamer using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer

The title reveals the essence of the problem, but it is more specific

I use [Brave](https://github.com/bbc/brave/) to generate a stream and [OvenMediaEngine](https://airensoft.gitbook.io/ovenmediaengine/) (hereinafter referred to as OME) as a media server

The problem is that Brave is built on gstreamer and OME is built on ffmpeg

Gstreamer uses nanoseconds to measure time, ffmpeg uses milliseconds. Because of this, when I stream from Brave to OME, I get the following logs

```
ovenmediaengine_1  | [2021-09-22 11:45:34.832] W [InboundWorker:17] MediaRouter | mediarouter_stream.cpp:1044 | Detected abnormal increased timestamp. track:1 last.pts: 1005022355050, cur.pts: 1009317322368, tb(1/1000), diff: 4294967ms
ovenmediaengine_1  | [2021-09-22 11:45:34.854] W [InboundWorker:17] MediaRouter | mediarouter_stream.cpp:1044 | Detected abnormal increased timestamp. track:1 last.pts: 1009317322368, cur.pts: 1013612289685, tb(1/1000), diff: 4294967ms
ovenmediaengine_1  | [2021-09-22 11:45:34.856] W [InboundWorker:17] MediaRouter | mediarouter_stream.cpp:1044 | Detected abnormal increased timestamp. track:0 last.pts: 1009317322359, cur.pts: 1013612289688, tb(1/1000), diff: 4294967ms
ovenmediaengine_1  | [2021-09-22 11:45:34.897] W [InboundWorker:17] MediaRouter | mediarouter_stream.cpp:1044 | Detected abnormal increased timestamp. track:1 last.pts: 1013612289706, cur.pts: 1017907257024, tb(1/1000), diff: 4294967ms
ovenmediaengine_1  | [2021-09-22 11:45:34.897] W [InboundWorker:17] MediaRouter | mediarouter_stream.cpp:1044 | Detected abnormal increased timestamp. track:0 last.pts: 1013612289688, cur.pts: 1017907257051, tb(1/1000), diff: 4294967ms
ovenmediaengine_1  | [2021-09-22 11:45:34.921] W [InboundWorker:17] MediaRouter | mediarouter_stream.cpp:1044 | Detected abnormal increased timestamp. track:0 last.pts: 1017907257051, cur.pts: 1022202224313, tb(1/1000), diff: 4294967ms
ovenmediaengine_1  | [2021-09-22 11:45:34.939] W [InboundWorker:17] MediaRouter | mediarouter_stream.cpp:1044 | Detected abnormal increased timestamp. track:1 last.pts: 1017907257045, cur.pts: 1022202224362, tb(1/1000), diff: 4294967ms
ovenmediaengine_1  | [2021-09-22 11:45:34.961] W [InboundWorker:17] MediaRouter | mediarouter_stream.cpp:1044 | Detected abnormal increased timestamp. track:1 last.pts: 1022202224362, cur.pts: 1026497191680, tb(1/1000), diff: 4294967ms
ovenmediaengine_1  | [2021-09-22 11:45:34.963] W [InboundWorker:17] MediaRouter | mediarouter_stream.cpp:1044 | Detected abnormal increased timestamp. track:0 last.pts: 1022202224313, cur.pts: 1026497191676, tb(1/1000), diff: 4294967ms
ovenmediaengine_1  | [2021-09-22 11:45:34.984] W [InboundWorker:17] MediaRouter | mediarouter_stream.cpp:1044 | Detected abnormal increased timestamp. track:0 last.pts: 1026497191676, cur.pts: 1030792159005, tb(1/1000), diff: 4294967ms
ovenmediaengine_1  | [2021-09-22 11:45:35.003] W [InboundWorker:17] MediaRouter | mediarouter_stream.cpp:1044 | Detected abnormal increased timestamp. track:1 last.pts: 1026497191701, cur.pts: 1030792159018, tb(1/1000), diff: 4294967ms
ovenmediaengine_1  | [2021-09-22 11:45:35.025] W [InboundWorker:17] MediaRouter | mediarouter_stream.cpp:1044 | Detected abnormal increased timestamp. track:1 last.pts: 1030792159018, cur.pts: 1035087126336, tb(1/1000), diff: 4294967ms
ovenmediaengine_1  | [2021-09-22 11:45:35.026] W [InboundWorker:17] MediaRouter | mediarouter_stream.cpp:1044 | Detected abnormal increased timestamp. track:0 last.pts: 1030792159005, cur.pts: 1035087126335, tb(1/1000), diff: 4294967ms
ovenmediaengine_1  | [2021-09-22 11:45:35.046] W [InboundWorker:17] MediaRouter | mediarouter_stream.cpp:1044 | Detected abnormal increased timestamp. track:0 last.pts: 1035087126335, cur.pts: 1039382093697, tb(1/1000), diff: 4294967ms
```

and the behavior of the stream type:

1. I open the stream in VLC
2. I see one second of the video
3. The video freezes and I can't open it further

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? There is a solution, or at least the direction of the solution.

It is also worth saying that I used to use [rtsp-simple-server](https://github.com/aler9/rtsp-simple-server) and it worked fine

Comment: Clarification: ffmpeg uses microseconds internally. But the input *format* may deal in a timebase of one millisecond.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but unfortunately this does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the late reply. If you ask questions related to OvenMediaEngine on [GitHub Isseus](https://github.com/AirenSoft/OvenMediaEngine/issues), you can get quick answers.